# Wired NIC "Unclaimed" on NUC5i5RYH

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ethernet

Recently the Ethernet connection on my NUC5i5RYH stopped working, one day it was fine, the next it wasn't. I've tried a variety of things to diagnose and fix this issue.

ifconfig -a shows

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 700395  bytes 42370951 (42.3 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 700395  bytes 42370951 (42.3 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.1.25  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
    inet6 fe80::1baf:1704:fcf1:8bbe  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 00:21:5c:d2:31:51  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 250650  bytes 142163026 (142.1 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 59591  bytes 11880584 (11.8 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

lspci -nn | grep Eth shows this:

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (3) I218-V [8086:15a3] (rev 03)
```

sudo lshw -C network reveals that the Ethernet device is unclaimed:

```
 *-network UNCLAIMED       
   description: Ethernet controller
   product: Ethernet Connection (3) I218-V
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 19
   bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
   version: 03
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:aa100000-aa11ffff memory:aa13b000-aa13bfff ioport:2080(size=32)
*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Wireless 7265
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlp2s0
   version: 59
   serial: 00:21:5c:d2:31:51
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.8.0-27-generic firmware=22.361476.0 ip=192.168.1.25 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:46 memory:aa000000-aa001fff
```

Running dmesg | grep e1000e shows an error code:

```
[    0.944913] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 3.2.6-k
[    0.944914] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
[    0.945111] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
[    1.770398] e1000e: probe of 0000:00:19.0 failed with error -2
```

After many searches I've tried:

- Powering off the computer, unplugging the Ethernet cord, powering back on, and plugging the Ethernet cord back in - same issue
- Removing and re-adding the e1000e module with modprobe - no change
- Downloading the latest e1000e tarball from the Intel NUC site, only to have it say

  /bin/sh: 1: [: -ge: unexpected operator
  Makefile:181: *** *** Aborting the build. *** This driver is not supported on kernel versions older than 2.4.0.  Stop.

I even went so far as to start a Debian 8 install, going to the point where the network was detected - the installer didn't see the NIC either.

I'm not sure what to try next. While the wireless interface still works, I'd really like to sort out the wired connection and have it working too.

**UPDATE: 11/22/2016**
Here are the results from the diff command MariusMatutiae provided. I'll have to do some serious DuckDuckGo work to grok all of this.

```
    mark@fermata:~$ diff <(cat /proc/interrupts) <(modprobe e1000e 2>/dev/null || cat /proc/interrupts)
1,35d0
<            CPU0       CPU1       CPU2       CPU3       
<   0:         20          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC   2-edge      timer
<   1:          0          1          1          0  IR-IO-APIC   1-edge      i8042
<   3:          0          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC   3-edge      nuvoton-cir
<   8:          0          1          0          0  IR-IO-APIC   8-edge      rtc0
<   9:          0          1          3          0  IR-IO-APIC   9-fasteoi   acpi
<  12:          3          0          1          0  IR-IO-APIC  12-edge      i8042
<  23:          8          5         17          5  IR-IO-APIC  23-fasteoi   ehci_hcd:usb1
<  40:          0          0          0          0  DMAR-MSI   0-edge      dmar0
<  41:          0          0          0          0  DMAR-MSI   1-edge      dmar1
<  42:        137         61        151        560  IR-PCI-MSI 327680-edge      xhci_hcd
<  43:       4083       1400      36869       1544  IR-PCI-MSI 512000-edge      ahci[0000:00:1f.2]
<  44:       2506        211       6307        143  IR-PCI-MSI 32768-edge      i915
<  45:         12          0          0          2  IR-PCI-MSI 360448-edge      mei_me
<  46:        525          0         49         26  IR-PCI-MSI 442368-edge      snd_hda_intel:card1
<  47:        141         24        128       8568  IR-PCI-MSI 1048576-edge      iwlwifi
<  48:        617         39        728         56  IR-PCI-MSI 49152-edge      snd_hda_intel:card0
< NMI:          8         10          9          7   Non-maskable interrupts
< LOC:       9051       9355       9378       8757   Local timer interrupts
< SPU:          0          0          0          0   Spurious interrupts
< PMI:          8         10          9          7   Performance monitoring interrupts
< IWI:          0          0          0          0   IRQ work interrupts
< RTR:          3          0          0          0   APIC ICR read retries
< RES:       3722       3593       3893       3330   Rescheduling interrupts
< CAL:       1744       1586       1352       1744   Function call interrupts
< TLB:        229        200        127        168   TLB shootdowns
< TRM:          0          0          0          0   Thermal event interrupts
< THR:          0          0          0          0   Threshold APIC interrupts
< DFR:          0          0          0          0   Deferred Error APIC interrupts
< MCE:          0          0          0          0   Machine check exceptions
< MCP:          3          3          3          3   Machine check polls
< ERR:          7
< MIS:          0
< PIN:          0          0          0          0   Posted-interrupt notification event
< PIW:          0          0          0          0   Posted-interrupt wakeup event
```

As I am starting to suspect this is a hardware issue, I've filed a warranty claim with Intel. Waiting to hear back from them.

Comment: If it was working before and now even another distro can't see the wired interface, chances are the NIC itself died :/ .... to that though, you've got a probe error `e1000e: probe of 0000:00:19.0 failed with error -2` .. what else does `dmesg` show for errors?

Comment: dmesg | grep -C 3 error produces this output: [    1.770398] e1000e: probe of 0000:00:19.0 failed with error -2     [    8.049336] EXT4-fs (sda2): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro     [    8.269243] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-24.ucode failed with error -2
[    8.269256] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-23.ucode failed with error -2

Comment: I'm really starting to think this is a hardware fault. I guess it's time to file a claim with Intel.

Answer (score 0):

Tough problem. First, *unclaimed* means you have no driver for the interface, which we know to be the case from the *dmesg* output (in your comment):

```
 [ 1.770398] e1000e: probe of 0000:00:19.0 failed with error -2
```

I double checked that *e1000e* is the appropriate driver for your interface (8086:15a3), and indeed it is:

```
# modinfo e1000e | grep 8086 | grep -i 15a3
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015A3sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
```

Then I searched Google for

```
e1000e: probe of failed with error "-2"
```

Pls notice you need to quote *-2*, because the *-* is the *exclusion* operator ina Google search, so if you do not use quotes it will return all links which **do not** include *2*.

You can see for yourself there is no clear consensus as to what causes your problem: you can read [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/e1000/bugs/402/) a thorough discussion, with a recipe for solving the problem which only worked for one person, or [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/650953/intel-e1000e-ethernet-not-working) you find the success story of someone who fixed the problem by updating the driver, or even [here](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-7774788.html) the story of a guy who added an extra wifi card to work around the broken *e1000* driver only to find that, on re-powering up, the ethernet interface was working perfectly. The Google search above returns more of the same, including several people thinking this is a BIOS-related problem.

You may provide a tad more information by running these commands:

```
# rmmod e1000e
# diff <(cat /proc/interrupts) <(modprobe e1000e 2>/dev/null || cat /proc/interrupts)
```

which shows at least which interrupt is connected to the *e1000e* failure. The **deep** debugging required in your case should probably move from this.